# Instalar e usar o launch-navigator

Tags: apache-cordova, intel-xdk

Uso o Intel XDK.

Gostaria de saber como instalar e usar esse plugin https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator

Alguém conhece algum vídeo tutorial explicando como utilizar? Se tiver outro vídeo mostrando o procedimento para aprender também vale.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma rapaz me ajudou nesse forum http://forum.mobilezone.com.br/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=3#p8